# Powershell.Invoke() result is 0.

Tags: c#, powershell

I tried to run the following PowerShell command in my windows form application. But my result is always zero. (result.Count == 0). I have tried running the command in powershell ISE, it works just fine. Can anyone help?

```
string connectionUri = "https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/";
var passWord = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in "jmfmjxvgtyspzrns".ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);            
PSCredential credential = new PSCredential("myEmail@outlook.com", passWord);
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();

PSCommand command = new PSCommand();
command.AddCommand("New-PSSession");
command.AddParameter("ConfigurationName", "Microsoft.Exchange");
command.AddParameter("ConnectionUri", new Uri(connectionUri));
command.AddParameter("Credential", credential);
command.AddParameter("Authentication", "Basic");
powershell.Commands = command;
runspace.Open();
powershell.Runspace = runspace;
Collection<System.Management.Automation.PSObject> result = powershell.Invoke();
```

Comment: What's the value of `result` (not just the `.Count`)?

Comment: Is anything in `powershell.Streams.Error`?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. 
I added:

```
command.AddParameter("AllowRedirection");
```

It works now.